# How to change HTTP status code of AsyncResult using Scalatra

Tags: scala, akka, scalatra

I have created a simple controller (the code below is obfuscated and simplified, assume ask returns a future with a message).  What I am trying to do is change the HTTP code from something other than 200 (based on the actor result).

When executing the code below I see the result come back as expected, but with 200 instead of 404

```
   get("/:id") {
        new AsyncResult() {
          val is: Future[_] = ask(actor, message)(timeout.toMillis)
          is.onComplete { res =>
            res match {
              case Success(result:Any) => NotFound(result) //Not found is just an example of a different HTTP code other than 200
          }
       }
    }
```

another attempt was

```
case Success(result:Any) => {
   this.status_ = (404)
   result
}
```

In this case, I receive a NullPointerException because the `response` (HTTPServletResponse) is null, due to the fact that the response is on a separate thread.

**TL;DR**

How can one conditionally change the HTTP code of an AsyncResult/Future in Scalatra?

**Details**

Scala 2.11.6

Scalatra 2.3.0

Akka 2.3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging in the Scalatra `FutureSupport` mixin, I found:

```
implicit val response: HttpServletResponse = scalatraContext.response
```

defined as a member of `AsyncResult` which allows me change the status code of the HTTP request inside the onComplete callback.

Comment: Following your example i tried setting the status code on the implicit response, but am getting 500 status code 
is.onComplete { res =>
            res match {
              case Success(result:Any) => response.setStatus(422)
          }

Answer (score 0):

You actually can return `Future[ActionResult]` to `is` if you want. Then inside the `Future` you can return `Ok()`